# Pass the value of a button to a hidden field and save it to database

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-6

So my design is I have multiple display fields and one hidden field. Besides each row there are two buttons accept and reject.my point is when I click a button its value pass to the hidden field and submits automatically in the database.
when I try my code the button doesn't pass anything and I tried all the solutions related to this topic and nothing is working. what am I doing wrong?

controller:

```
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Add_Fulfillment ()
    {
        var getData = db.TBL_Request.Include(x=>x.TBL_Accounts).Include(x=>x.TBL_Accounts_LOBs).ToList() ;
        var add_fulfillment = new Add_Fulfillment();
        var ful_ = new fulfillmentVM();
        foreach (var data in getData)
        {
            List<Add_Fulfillment> fulfillment = db.TBL_Request.Select(i => new Add_Fulfillment
            {
                Request_ID = i.Request_ID,
                Employee_no = i.Employee_no,
                Operation_Date = i.Operation_Date,
                Fulfillment_Rate = i.Fulfillment_Rate ??0,
                Account_Name = i.TBL_Accounts.Account_Name,
                LOB = i.TBL_Accounts_LOBs.LOB,
                Status = i.Inserted_by
            }).ToList();
            ful_._Requests = fulfillment;
        }


        return View(ful_);
    }

     [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Add_Fulfillment_Accept(int Request_ID , int? Status)
    {
       var user= db.TBL_Request.Find(Request_ID);


        //hiddenfieldvalue assigns it to the field in the database i want to update

        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Add_Fulfillment");
    }
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Add_Fulfillment_Reject(int Request_ID)
    {
        return RedirectToAction("Add_Fulfillment");
    }
```

the view

```
@model Staff_Requisition.Models.fulfillmentVM

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Add_Fulfillment";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2>Add_Fulfillment</h2>

<!-- page content -->


<div class="right_col" role="main">
    <div class="">
        <div class="clearfix"></div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                <div class="x_panel">
                    <div class="x_title">
                        <h2>Plain Page</h2>
                        <div class="clearfix"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="x_content">
                        <table class="table">
                            <tr>
                                <th>
                                    Employee_no
                                </th>
                                <th>
                                    Operation_Date
                                </th>
                                <th>
                                    Fulfillment_Rate
                                </th>
                                <th>
                                    Account_Name
                                </th>
                                <th>
                                    LOB
                                </th>
                                <th></th>
                                <th></th>
                            </tr>

                            @for (int i = 0; i < Model._Requests.Count(); i++)
                            {
                                <tr>

                                    <td>
                                        @Html.DisplayFor(x => Model._Requests[i].Employee_no)
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        @Html.DisplayFor(x => Model._Requests[i].Operation_Date)
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        @Html.DisplayFor(x => Model._Requests[i].Fulfillment_Rate)
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        @Html.DisplayFor(x => Model._Requests[i].Account_Name)
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        @Html.DisplayFor(x => Model._Requests[i].LOB)
                                    </td>
                                    <td>

                                        @Html.Hidden("Status" , Model._Requests[i].Status , new { id = "myEdit" })

                                    </td>
                                    @using (Html.BeginForm("Add_Fulfillment_Accept", "TBL_Request", FormMethod.Post, new { @id = "myForm" }))
                                    {
                                        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
                                        <td>
                                            <button id="btnAccept" class="btn btn-lg btn-success" name="a_button" type="submit" value="122">Accept</button>
                                            @Html.Hidden("Request_ID", Model._Requests[i].Request_ID)
                                        </td>
                                    }
                                    @using (Html.BeginForm("Add_Fulfillment_Reject", "TBL_Request", FormMethod.Post, new { @id = "myForm" }))
                                    {
                                        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
                                        <td>
                                            <button id="btnReject" class="btn btn-lg btn-danger" name="button" type="submit" value="222">Reject</button>
                                            @Html.Hidden("Request_ID", Model._Requests[i].Request_ID)
                                        </td>
                                    }
                                </tr>

                            }

                        </table>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<!-- /page content -->


@section Scripts {
    <script>

        $("#btnAccept").click(function () {
            $("#myEdit").val($("#btnAccept").val());

        })

        $("#btnReject").click(function () {
            $("#myEdit").val($("#btnReject").val());

        })


    </script>
}
```

Comment: First thing is, selector `#myEdit` will not work since there would be multiple `#myEdit`s on the page as it is inside a for-loop. Try giving unique id to each. Same for `#btnAccept` and `#btnReject`.

Comment: just uncomment   //db.TBL_Request.Add(request);  this line and then try

Comment: you can get button and hidden field value's by using jquery and ajax dont use formpost.

Comment: @ImranLuhur could you please refer a link to follow or what to look for.

Comment: hey, @AdityaBhave how would you suggest I do it. if there is a link or a tutorial to follow, that would be great or you have any suggestions for another approach to achieve what I need . for giving a unique id for each hidden field that means I need to write it a lot of times.

Comment: @IshwarGagare I tried it. it won't work.

Comment: i iterate it the view and made two form methods for each button . in the controller i made a method for each one of the buttons. my issue is how to access the hidden field value and put it in the database `[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Add_Fulfillment_Accept(int Request_ID )
        {
           var user= db.TBL_Request.Find(Request_ID);
           
            //hiddenfieldvalue assigns it to the field in the database i want to update
            
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Add_Fulfillment");
        } `

Comment: Just simplify your code. Add an `onclick="accept(122)"` and `onclick="reject(222)"` to your button which calls a function with those names. Remove the code `$("#myForm").submit();` or change your button type to `button` to prevent 2 submissions.

Comment: @SteveGreene so my accept function would be the same as the passing value function I wrote just change the name?

Comment: @SteveGreene i wrote the function that way . is this right?  `function accept(value) {
            $("#myEdit").val(vlaue);
        }`

Answer (score 0):

I solved it. the only issue was I didn't put the hidden field of the status inside the form .that's why it never passes the value. thank you for all your efforts though!
view:

```
                                    @using (Html.BeginForm("Add_Fulfillment_Accept", "TBL_Request", FormMethod.Post))
                                    {
                                        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
                                    <td>
                                        <button id="btnAccept" class="btn btn-lg btn-success" name="a_button" type="submit" onclick="accept(122)" value="122">Accept</button>
                                        @Html.Hidden("Request_ID", Model._Requests[i].Request_ID)
                                        @Html.Hidden("Status", Model._Requests[i].Status, new { id = "myEdit", value = "" })
                                    </td>
                                    }
                                    @using (Html.BeginForm("Add_Fulfillment_Reject", "TBL_Request", FormMethod.Post))
                                    {
                                        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
                                    <td>
                                        <button id="btnReject" class="btn btn-lg btn-danger" name="button" type="submit" onclick="reject(222)" value="222">Reject</button>
                                        @Html.Hidden("Request_ID", Model._Requests[i].Request_ID)
                                        @Html.Hidden("Status", Model._Requests[i].Status, new { id = "myEdit", value = "" })
                                    </td>
                                    }
                                </tr>

                            }

                        </table>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<!-- /page content -->


@section Scripts {
    <script>
         $('[name = "a_button"]').click(function () {
            $('[name = "Status"]').val($('[name = "a_button"]').val());

        })

        $('[name = "button"]').click(function () {
            $('[name = "Status"]').val($('[name = "button"]').val());

        })


    </script>
```